# Missing Spring Properties Yaml Editor and and Spring Properties Editor with Spring Tools 3.9.2

Tags: spring-tool-suite

I had installed an earlier version of [Spring Tools](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/spring-tools-aka-spring-ide-and-spring-tool-suite) into an existing Eclipse Oxygen installation and I was able to select and use the **Spring Properties Yaml Editor** and **Spring Properties Editor** using the `Open With...` context menu but since upgrading to Spring Tools 3.9.2 those two editors are missing. Instead now I need to use plain text editors or something like YEdit YAML Editor which doesn't give me any of the nice spring related features.

This is the same question as the first half of [eclipse-spring-tools-missing-content-assist-autocomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48093885/eclipse-spring-tools-missing-content-assist-autocomplete) but that part of the question was never solved.

If I install a fresh copy of Spring Tool Suite 4 (which is a rebadged eclipse with the same plugin installed by default) then those required editors are present, so this is only a problem when working with Vanilla Eclipse with Spring Tools 3.9.2.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I took a deeper look and I think I figured out what the problem is. Due to a slightly refactored feature structure, the property editing support resides in a different feature now. If you installed STS from the marketplace and updated it to 3.9.2, the feature that contains the property editing did not get installed automatically.

The fix is easy: Go to `Install New Software` and select the STS update site that you should already have in the list of available update sites. Then expand the `Extensions / Spring IDE` section and select `Spring IDE Boot Support`. Install that and you get the property editing support back (and updated with future updates, too).

Comment: It may be worth mentioning that this packaging problem in the marketplace definition is fixed. So in the future this workaround of installing the boot support explicitly will not be necessary.

Comment: The URL you're referring to is (currently) http://dist.springsource.com/release/TOOLS/update/e4.7/

I also needed to uncheck the 'Hide items' checkbox and check the 'Group items' checkbox to fit your answer.

Comment: This did the trick, thanks! I didn't think to look there, looks like there's other goodies in there that haven't been installed either.

Comment: Spring Tool Suite 4 - https://download.springsource.com/release/TOOLS/sts4/update/e4.9/

Comment: I have the same issue, Eclipse version 2019-06 (4.12), Spring Tools 3.9.9. I tried to add missing components via Software Update dialogue. Used https://download.springsource.com/release/TOOLS/sts4/update/e4.12/ repository, but "Spring IDE Boot Support" is absent in the list of available components:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3FeSr.png

Comment: Finally managed to resolve it with repository https://download.springsource.com/release/TOOLS/update/e4.11/ (it's important, TOOLS/update/, not TOOLS/sts4). All other update repositories of STS were disabled, flag "contact all update sites during install to find required software" was set ON.

Comment: In case you want to install additional STS3 components into an STS3 installation or Eclipse base install, you should indeed use the `release/TOOLS/update/e...` update site, not the one for STS4, which is the update site for the STS 4 releases. But please make sure to use the matching `e4.x` update site, so for Eclipse 2019-06, please use the one that ends with `e4.12`, not the `e4.11`.

Answer (score 1):

**Updated Fix site for the Autocomplete option for the Spring Boot IDE support.**

The fix is easy: Go to Install New Software and select the STS update site (org.springsource.sts.product - http://dist.springsource.com/release/TOOLS/update/3.9.2.RELEASE/e4.7) that you should already have in the list of available update sites. Then expand the Extensions / Spring IDE section and select Spring IDE Boot Support. Install that and you get the property editing support back (and updated with future updates, too).